# Extract submatrix of unknown size from bigger matrix while values are equal to specified value

Tags: c++, matrix, submatrix

So let's say we have this matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

And we need those outputs:

Submatrix 1:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

Submatrix 2:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

The matrix size can vary, so can the submatrix sizes but they will have either square or rectangle shape. And is only 0 and 1.

How can i do that? Is there any algorithm to do that?

```
for (i=0; i<m;i++){
    for (j=2; j<n; j++){
        if ( A[i+1,j]==1 && A[i,j+1]==1 || A[i+1,j]==1 && A[i,j-1]==1 || A[i-1,j]==1 && A[i,j+1]==1 || A[i-1,j]==1 && A[i,j-1]==1 || A[i-1,j]==1 && A[i+1,j]==1 && A[i,j-1]==1 && A[i,j+1]==1 )
           B[i,j]=A[i,j];


        }
}
```

This is the first ideea that comes to my mind, but i don't know how to stop after i'm done with the first block of ones, and in the end the matrix B is the same as matrix A. Also i don't know how to set the submatrix size to be exactly the size that it needs to be. For now i'm only trying to break the big matrix in 2. Should i allocate the submatrix dynamically?

Comment: What is the maximum and minimum allowed sub matrix size? Is size=(1,1) allowed? Is the input only 0 and 1? Is the matrix always quadratic?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX You should read more carefully, these information are already provided.

Comment: The sentence "And is only 0 and 1" has no semantic content. What is only 0 and 1? You refer to sizes of sub matrices, but dont answer my question if a 1-element matrix is allowed, too. And every matrix has the form of a square or a rectangle, so this information doesn't help at all

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I'll translate for you: The matrix size can be anything, same thing for the submatrices sizes. The matrices shapes can be quadratic or rectangular. The whole matrix contains only `0` (for empty spaces) and `1` (for submatrices to catch).

Comment: 0 and 1 are the values allowed in the matrix as you can see in the example. And yes, the matrix size can vary ( bigger or smaller ) meaning it can go up to something like 2000x2000 or 10x10, even 1x1 if you want but 1x1 is nonsense because the submatrix is the matrix itself, right?

Comment: @Fareanor could you please provide an example for a non-quadratic/non-rectangular matrix-shape? And what is an "empty space" in a matrix? It is not about not understanding the question at all.I understand what he wants, but the wording is bad

Comment: @myname123321 He was asking _1x1_ for submatrix size not for the upper matrix :)

Comment: @RoQuOTriX What a bad faith, we know that the english is bad, but it is still easy to understand. If you are unpleased, why don't you propose an edit ? Or at least go on your way. No need to be that aggressive, it does not help anyone :)

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I'm sorry, english is not my first language, but the examples should be pretty straight forward. An algorithm should work for any case not just for the example that i provided. I tried to work on that problem but my knowledge is limited. I'm not that good when it comes to algorithms.

Comment: What have you tried? What are the problems you are facing?

Comment: And also, just for fun: how would you treat this (more than 1 solution)?
1 0 0 \newline
1 1 1 \newline
1 1 1 \newline

Comment: @MFnx I tried to take the matrix element by element and see if it has neighbours which are aswell 1 but this just duplicates my matrix. I can't find the solution to stop after let's say the first submatrix. Your example can be done with an array of arrays because you can't have a matrix that has 1 element on first row, and 3 on the next two rows ... right?

Comment: But, regardless of C++ and coding... just with a paper and a pencil. What would the solution of 1 0 0 \newline 1 1 1 \newline 1 1 1 \newline be?

Comment: @MFnx Check neighbours of current element. If one of them is 1 then our current element is a part of our block of ones, right?

Comment: Neighbour to the right? Neighbour downwards? Left, upwards? Let's say you mean to the right. Then you would have 1 submatrix of 1, and another submatrices of 2 times 3 ones. Ok, well, give it a try! If you encounter problems, ask a good question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MFnx should i ask a new question providing my code or should i edit this one?

Comment: As you please. Editing is just fine imo.

Comment: Just for my clarifying: The 2nd sub-matrix (3 x 2) can be found in the exposed matrix sample 3 times?

Comment: @myname123321 The question of MFnx is very important. If you have 1 0 0 \newline 1 1 1 \newline 1 1 1, will you consider you have a (1x1) matrix with a (2x3) matrix below ? Or will you consider you have a (3x1) matrix to the left and a (2x2) matrix ? More clearly, can a submatrix be right next to another one ?

Comment: Sorry for being late. I forgot to mention that a case like 1 0 0 \newline 1 1 1 \newline 1 1 1 should be ignored, because inputs like this would not be tested.